# Understanding sunburstR behaviour

Tags: r, plot, sunburst-diagram

I have a `data.frame` that looks similar to this example:

```
> head(dd)
#  paths counts
#1     s   4735
#2    dt   4635
#3    so   2191
#4    sb   1949
#5 dt-dt   1310
#6   s-s    978
```

where different steps in a path are separated by `-`. As you can see, some paths are length 1, some are > 1 step (up to 5 steps in the example).

Now I would like to visualize the data as a `sunburst` plot using the `sunburstR` package. I do it like this:

```
# devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/sunburstR")
library(sunburstR)
sunburst(dd)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't produce any output and I don't understand why. As another example, this works as expected:

```
sunburst(tail(dd, 8))
```

but this doesn't:

```
sunburst(tail(dd, 9))
```

I also noticed that

```
sunburst(dd[c(5, 1:4),])
```

produces a plot, but surprisingly, the `dt` category is spit into two chunks, where it should normally be displayed as a single chunk on the first (innermost) level.

**Q:** Can someone explain to me why this would happen (some approaches work, some don't and some work but display the data somewhat incorrectly) and what I need to do to visualize the whole data set (more than just the sample data)?

**Sample data**

```
dd <- structure(list(paths = c("s", "dt", "so", "sb", "dt-dt", "s-s", 
"so-dt", "dt-dt-dt", "sb-sb", "so-so", "s-s-s", "s-rd", "dt-dt-dt-dt", 
"s-sb", "a", "so-dt-dt", "s-rd-rd", "r", "dt-s", "so-sb", "dt-sb", 
"s-rd-rd-rd", "dt-rd", "dt-dt-dt-dt-dt", "so-dt-dt-dt"), counts = c(4735L, 
4635L, 2191L, 1949L, 1310L, 978L, 558L, 455L, 324L, 281L, 266L, 
231L, 208L, 200L, 200L, 196L, 156L, 150L, 142L, 129L, 123L, 114L, 
113L, 113L, 100L)), .Names = c("paths", "counts"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: Maybe it chokes because of doubled (sub)sequences? E.g. `s-rd-rd` is part of `s-rd-rd-rd`.

Comment: @lukeA, thanks, that might be true. I'll try to investigate that a bit. However, it's essential for my data that `s-rd-rd` and `s-rd-rd-rd` are equal only the first 3 levels but differ on the 4th so I can't just unite them into a single category

Comment: I think the package author appends an additional `-end` in such cases.

Comment: @lukeA, yep, I just did the same and everything seems to work. Wanna post as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dd` contains sequences that are subsequences of of others:

```
tail(dd, 9)
#             paths counts
# 17        s-rd-rd    156 # <-----
# 18              r    150
# 19           dt-s    142
# 20          so-sb    129
# 21          dt-sb    123
# 22     s-rd-rd-rd    114 # <-----
# 23          dt-rd    113
# 24 dt-dt-dt-dt-dt    113
# 25    so-dt-dt-dt    100
```

E.g. `s-rd-rd` is part of `s-rd-rd-rd`. `sunburst` seems to choke on that. 
In the [package author's example](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/7/2/week-26-sunburstr) you'll notice an additional 
`-end` to prevent such cases. This is also mentioned in the [tips here](https://gist.github.com/kerryrodden/7090426):

> each line should be a complete path from root to leaf - don't include
>   counts for intermediate steps. For example, include "home-search-end"
>   and "home-search-product-end" but not "home-search" - the latter is
>   computed by the partition layout, by adding up the counts of all the
>   sequences with that prefix.

This seems to do the trick here, too:

```
transform(tail(dd, 9), paths=paste0(paths, "-end"))
#                 paths counts
# 17        s-rd-rd-end    156
# 18              r-end    150
# 19           dt-s-end    142
# 20          so-sb-end    129
# 21          dt-sb-end    123
# 22     s-rd-rd-rd-end    114
# 23          dt-rd-end    113
# 24 dt-dt-dt-dt-dt-end    113
# 25    so-dt-dt-dt-end    100

sunburst(transform(tail(dd, 9), paths=paste0(paths, "-end")))
```

[image]

Comment: some additional discussion on very similar issue here on github https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/issues/21